# Can Kivy be used in conjunction with the latest Python distribution?

Tags: python, compatibility, kivy

I"ve just barely started using [kivy](http://www.kivy.org) and followed the [kivy basics tutorial](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/basic.html) and noticed that the latest download of the kivy library was named "Kivy-1.9.0-py2.7-win32-x86" implying that it is optimized for developing with (or just written in) py2.7 and NOT py3.o+. My question is can kivy be trustingly used for an app written in py3? My app specifically needs py3 changes concerning the [unicode](http://unicode.org) overhaul that happened with the new release. Will I run into any compatibility issues? If so, is there another library out there that will ease app development while using a newer distribution of Python? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I don't know where you were looking, but on the [official download page](http://kivy.org/#download), there are Windows binaries for both Python 2.7 and 3.4.

Also, from [the Kivy FAQ](http://kivy.org/docs/faq.html#does-kivy-support-python-3-x):

> Does Kivy support Python 3.x?
>
> Yes! As of version 1.8.0 Kivy supports both Python >= 2.7 and Python >= 3.3 with the same codebase.
>
> However, be aware that while Kivy will run in Python 3.3+, packaging support is not yet complete. If you plan to create mobile apps for Android or iOS, you should use Python 2.7 for now.

3.x support is still relatively newish, but the fact that they're distribution official releases for 3.4 implies that you shouldn't have many compatibility issues, except for the one they mention above.

Of course if you're planning to use any third-party modules that aren't part of Kivy, you will want to check them all for 3.x compatibility too.

---

As a side note, on this:

> If so, is there another library out there that will ease app development while using a newer distribution of Python?

Kivy is a pretty unique framework that would be hard to just replace with a different library without pretty much rethinking your whole app. Without knowing exactly why you chose Kivy and what exactly you were hoping to get out of it, it would be hard for anyone else to tell you what to try. (And, even with that information, it probably wouldn't be an appropriate question for StackOverflow.)

Comment: Oops! Easy fix. Thank you and I should definitely look farther into exactly why I chose kivy.